# Image auto-resize in Bootstrap-3 carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap-3 carousel with 3 images showing each time. There are four rounds of 3 images each. I want that the images auto-resize to the optimal maximised width and height for each device dimension (large desktop, tablet, phone). So for example, phones will have 100x100, large desktops 300x300. And that the images, regardless of uploaded dimensions, scale to those optimal maximised dimensions for each device. I know that the solution lies here:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

But how do I define the optimal height and width for my div(S)? And since I have multiple div classes for each device dimension, is it then possible to set the optimal maximised height and width?

Here link to my bootply.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/owKdCnv6Bo)

Here my code for HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-home">
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-example- generic">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-generic">  </li>
    </ol><!-- Slider Content (Wrapper for slides )-->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x100&amp;text=AAAAAAA">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x145&amp;text=BBBBBB"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/225x300&amp;text=CCCCCCC">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x250&amp;text=DDDDDDD">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x150&amp;text=EEEEEEEE">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/310x180&amp;text=FFFFFFF">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/290x140&amp;text=GGGGGGGG">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x300&amp;text=HHHHHHHHH">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x120&amp;text=IIIIIIIIII">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x50&amp;text=JJJJJJJJJ">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/270x170&amp;text=KKKKKK">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x155&amp;text=LLLLLLLL">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    <br>
</div></div>
```

Here my CSS:

```
.carousel-home {
margin-left:39px;
margin-right:39px;
}

.carousel-indicators li { visibility: hidden; }

.carousel-inner .item {
font-size:10px;
color:#0404B4
}

.carousel-control {
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 30px;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right { 
background:#000000;
}

.carousel-control.left { left: -2px; }
.carousel-control.right { right: -2px; }`
```

Answer (score 0):

tell me if this works and i´ll help you!

```
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x145&amp;text=BBBBBB">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/225x300&amp;text=CCCCCCC">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x250&amp;text=DDDDDDD">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x150&amp;text=EEEEEEEE">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/310x180&amp;text=FFFFFFF">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/290x140&amp;text=GGGGGGGG">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x300&amp;text=HHHHHHHHH">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x120&amp;text=IIIIIIIIII">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x50&amp;text=JJJJJJJJJ">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/270x170&amp;text=KKKKKK">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x155&amp;text=LLLLLLLL">
                </div>
            </div>
```

if you want different sizes for all the devices you only heve to use the media queries properly like this:

```
/*pc´s and big screens */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}

/* Tablets an medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}
/* Tablets portrait and small desktops*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
}
/* landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}
/* landscape phones and small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

and add the specific widths and heights for each device.
Did you mean this or you want another thing?

Comment: can u elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: thanks. I understood where to add the img class, but I still have this problem...  I want that the images auto-resize to the optimal maximised width and height for each device dimension. E.g. phones will have 100x100, large desktops 300x300. And that the images, regardless of uploaded dimensions, scale to those optimal maximised dimensions for each device. New Bootply... http://www.bootply.com/94vC66jWCC - All uploaded images with different dimensions should have the same dimensions for each device when running the carousel, thats the objective. Now you see all different size images.